# How to change "Shipping & Handling" label to "Order Shipping & Handling" in admin order create form?

Tags: magento2.2.3

How to change "Shipping & Handling" label to "Order Shipping & Handling" in admin order create form and order success email in magento 2.2.3?

Answer (score 0):

Create en_US.csv in your theme folder

```
app/design/frontend/Vendor/Theme/i18n/en_US.csv
```

change the "Shipping & Handling" to "Order Shipping & Handling"

clear cache in command line

```
php bin/magento cache:clear
```

Refer the below **core file-path**

```
vendor/magento/module-sales/i18n/en_US.csv
```

Hope this will help you.

Comment: I want to change in whole website "Shipping & Handling" to "Order Shipping & Handling"